# Connecting Two Windows 10 Asus Laptops

Tags: home-networking

How do I connect several Asus laptops so that information can be entered in the host laptop, and the host computer can share applications with other laptops without using Ethernet or Internet at a work place?

Comment: "Without using Ethernet or Internet at a work place?" best start working on your wizardry skills. If this is possible, you'll need wifi or some sort of connectivity between the machines.

Comment: I assume you meant `without using Ethernet` as `not using network`

Answer (score 0):

**How to connect two Windows computers to transfer files to each other via ethernet cable only**

1. Navigate to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings
2. Right click on "Ethernet" and click Properties
3. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPV4) under the Networking tab. Click Properties.
4. Set IP address of one computer to 192.168.0.1 and the other to 192.168.0.2. Set both subnet masks to 255.255.255.0
5. Physically connect the two computers with an ethernet computer.
6. Try to ping each other. From the computer with 192.168.0.1 open command prompt and type `ping 192.168.0.2` and you should see `Reply from 192.168.0.2`. Repeat for the other computer.
7. Ensure both workgroups have the same name.
8. Enable folder or drive to be shared that you wish to share.

**The overall process (independent of Windows) is:**

1. Assign IP addresses / subnets manually
2. Connect together
3. Enable sharing something
4. View files.